# How to run application under secondary GMSA in Docker container?

Tags: docker, managed-service-accounts

The [Microsoft documentation about creating GMSA's for Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts) reads:

> Containers can also be configured with additional gMSAs, in case you want to run a service or application in the container as a different identity from the container computer account.

This is exactly what I want to do. So I created a credential spec like this:

`New-CredentialSpec -AccountName WebApp01 -AdditionalAccounts LogAgentSvc`

Now I want to run an application under the LogAgentSvc service account, but how can I do that? When reading the [Configure your app docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-configure-app), you aren't supposed to run an application under a GMSA directly. Instead, you are advised to run the application (or service) under "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE". Whilst the introduction of the docs on that page mention the ability to run an application under a secondary GMSA, the steps to do that aren't outlined.
I have tried to run the service in question under the GMSA directly, but that gives me an usual logon error.